# @stripe/firestore-stripe-payments getProducts() results in FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference ..."

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a Next JS Netflix clone application, and I'm at the point of implementing Stripe with Firebase. Currently, I have configured Stripe with my Firestore online, and am now trying to retrieve the products I've created. I installed the @stripe/firestore-stripe-payments dependency and am using the getProducts() using payments and options as the required arguments. However, it kept giving me this error:

FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

I have updated all dependencies. I also needed to transpile the @stripe/firestore-stripe-payments beforehand from some other error, so maybe this is causing the issue, but I hope not. I tried debugging on VSCode, but it gets very easy to get lost.

Here's my code:
stripe.ts

```
import {
createCheckoutSession,
  getStripePayments,
} from "@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments";

import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "@firebase/functions";

import app from "../firebase";

const payments = getStripePayments(app, {
  productsCollection: "products",
  customersCollection: "customers",
});

const loadCheckout = async (priceId: string) => {
  await createCheckoutSession(payments, {price: priceId, success_url: window.location.origin,
  cancel_url: window.location.origin,})
  .then(snapshot => window.location.assign(snapshot.url)).catch(error => console.log(error.message))
}

export {loadCheckout}
export default payments
```

firebase.ts

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { getApp, getApps, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: [api-Key],
  authDomain: [authDomain],
  projectId: [projectId],
  storageBucket: [storageBucket],
  messagingSenderId: [messagingSenderId],
  appId: [appId],
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();
const db = getFirestore();
const auth = getAuth();

export default app;
export { auth, db };
```

getProducts function call

```
import { Product, getProducts } from "@stripe/firestore-stripe-

payments";
import { useRecoilValue } from "recoil";
import { modalState, movieState } from "@/atoms/modalAtom";
import Banner from "@/components/Banner";
import Header from "@/components/Header";
import Modal from "@/components/Modal";
import Plans from "@/components/Plans";
import Row from "@/components/Row";
import useAuth from "@/hooks/useAuth";
import payments from "@/lib/stripe";
import { Movie } from "@/typings";
import requests from "@/utils/request";

interface Props {
  netflixOriginals: Movie[];
  trendingNow: Movie[];
  topRated: Movie[];
  actionMovies: Movie[];
  comedyMovies: Movie[];
  horrorMovies: Movie[];
  romanceMovies: Movie[];
  documentaries: Movie[];
  products: Product[]
}

// provide types; typescript provides intellisense
const Home = ({ netflixOriginals,
trendingNow,
topRated,
actionMovies,
comedyMovies,
horrorMovies,
romanceMovies,
documentaries, 
products}: Props) => {
  console.log(products)
  const {logout, loading} = useAuth()
  const showModal = useRecoilValue(modalState)
  const subscription = false

  if(loading || subscription === null) return null

  if(!subscription) return <Plans/>
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <main className="relative pl-4 pb-24 lg:space-y-24 lg:pl-16">
        <Banner netflixOriginals={netflixOriginals} />
        <section className="md:space-y-24">
        <Row title="Trending Now" movies={trendingNow} />
          <Row title="Top Rated" movies={topRated} />
          <Row title="Action Thrillers" movies={actionMovies} />
          {/* My List Component */}
          <Row title="Comedies" movies={comedyMovies} />
          <Row title="Scary Movies" movies={horrorMovies} />
          <Row title="Romance Movies" movies={romanceMovies} />
          <Row title="Documentaries" movies={documentaries} />
        </section>
      </main>
      {showModal && <Modal/>}
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const products = await getProducts(payments, {
    includePrices: true,
    activeOnly: true,
  }).catch((error) => console.log(error.message))

  const [
    netflixOriginals,
    trendingNow,
    topRated,
    actionMovies,
    comedyMovies,
    horrorMovies,
    romanceMovies,
    documentaries,
  ] = await Promise.all([
    fetch(requests.fetchNetflixOriginals).then((res) => res.json()),
    fetch(requests.fetchTrending).then((res) => res.json()),
    fetch(requests.fetchTopRated).then((res) => res.json()),
    fetch(requests.fetchActionMovies).then((res) => res.json()),
    fetch(requests.fetchComedyMovies).then((res) => res.json()),
    fetch(requests.fetchHorrorMovies).then((res) => res.json()),
    fetch(requests.fetchRomanceMovies).then((res) => res.json()),
    fetch(requests.fetchDocumentaries).then((res) => res.json()),
  ]);


  return {
    props: {
      netflixOriginals: netflixOriginals.results,
      trendingNow: trendingNow.results,
      topRated: topRated.results,
      actionMovies: actionMovies.results,
      comedyMovies: comedyMovies.results,
      horrorMovies: horrorMovies.results,
      romanceMovies: romanceMovies.results,
      documentaries: documentaries.results,
      products,
    },
  }
}
```

dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
"@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
"@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
"@mui/material": "^5.14.1",
"@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.12.0",
"@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments": "^0.0.6",
"@types/node": "20.4.2",
"@types/react": "18.2.15",
"@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
"autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
"eslint": "8.45.0",
"eslint-config-next": "13.4.10",
"firebase": "^10.0.0",
"next": "^13.4.10",
"next-transpile-modules": "^10.0.1",
"postcss": "8.4.26",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"react-hook-form": "^7.45.2",
"react-icons": "^4.10.1",
"react-player": "^2.12.0",
"recoil": "^0.7.7",
"styled-components": "^5.3.11",
"tailwind": "^4.0.0",
"tailwind-scrollbar-hide": "^1.1.7",
"tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
"typescript": "5.1.6"
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, this is an issue with `@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments` itself. See [this](https://github.com/invertase/stripe-firebase-extensions/issues/304) github issue.

Quoting from a comment in that issue:

> This is likely a dependency management issue. The library is expecting a certain version of @firebase/firestore while a different one is installed with the app

Personally, I would recommend ditchng the dependency, as it isn't too much work to implement the functionality yourself. For example, you could get products like this:

```js
import { query, collection, where, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';

// create a query object
const q = query(
    collection(db, 'products'), 
    where('active', '==', true)
);

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);


// for each product, get the product price info
const productsPromises = querySnapshot.docs.map(async (productDoc) => {
    let productInfo = productDoc.data();

    // fetch prices subcollection per product
    const pricesCollection = collection(productDoc.ref, 'prices');
    const priceQuerySnapshot = await getDocs(pricesCollection);

    // assume there is only one price per product
    const priceDoc = priceQuerySnapshot.docs[0];
    productInfo['priceId'] = priceDoc.id;
    productInfo['priceInfo'] = priceDoc.data();
    return productInfo;
});

// 'products' is an array of products (including price info)
const products = await Promise.all(productsPromises);
```

If you're interested, [this article](https://medium.com/@lkuppers11/processing-payments-in-firebase-with-stripe-e90c816f02d0) shows how to implement basic stripe functionality without using `@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments`.

Comment: Good answer mate. it is indeed super simple to get your own products since you're already using Firestore, and probably supremely bad practice to try do it using a seemingly unmaintained library that obviously has issues instead of just a simple Firestore query. @MannyFresh I'd recommend you give this man his check mark.